# Oracle MAF-MCS Connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf, mcs

I have created one Custom API in Oracle MCS for login authentication and I have an Application built in MAF. My doubt is how to call this Custom API from Oracle MAF application?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `OEPE` (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse), you can use this tutorial for consuming any REST service API,

- [Building MAF Applications using OEPE and REST Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_oepe_maf_rest_json/tut_oepe_maf_rest_1.html)

For `MCS-MAF` support, the following YouTube should help,

- [MAF: (OEPE) Using a RAML document to help consume REST services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWUj978cSQ8)
- You can get the [latest version of OEPE from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I am using JDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MAF MCS Utility app (should be in your public examples folder) especially the source code.

More info can also be [found in this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/maf_mcs_utility_accessing_oracle).

**Short code example:**

```
MBEConfiguration mbeConfiguration = 
    new MBEConfiguration(
          <mbe rest connection>,<mobileBackendId>,
          <anonymous key string>,<application key string>, 
          MBEConfiguration.AuthenticationType.BASIC_AUTH);
 mbeConfiguration.setEnableAnalytics(true);
 mbeConfiguration.setLoggingEnabled(false)
 mbeConfiguration.setMobileDeviceId(
         DeviceManagerFactory.getDeviceManager().getName());
 MBE mobileBackend = MBEManager.getManager().
         createOrRenewMobileBackend(<mobile backend Id>, mbeConfiguration);

CustomAPI customApiProxy = mbe.getServiceProxyCustomApi();
UserInfo userInfo = mobileBackend.getServiceProxyUserInfo();
Analytics analyticsProxy = mobileBackend.getServiceProxyAnalytics();
Storage storageProxy = mobileBackend.getServiceProxyStorage();
```